# How do I redirect my client to a different page according to their browser?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, browser

I have found some HTML code online to help me do this, but it does not work when I try it on Firefox or Internet Explorer. Could I have some help to try and achieve this?

Here is the code I found

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    if(navigator.appName == "Mozilla")
    {
     window.location = "ff/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
     window.location = "ie/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appName == "Google Chrome")
    {
     window.location = "ch/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appName == "Safari")
    {
     window.location = "sa/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appName == "Google Chrome")
    {
     window.location = "ch/index.html"
    }
     window.location == "un/index.html"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to determine the browser in JavaScript is always tricky and never reliable. In your case it is not working because `navigator.appName` in Firefox (at least version 12.0) returns... `"Netscape"`.

A little bit more reliable is the usage of `navigator.userAgent` which returns: `""Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0""` on my computer.

Even better, check out [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) - which is deprecated for a reason, see above.

Which brings us to the question: why do you need this? Modern web applications should discover browser capabilities rather than relying on the actual browser.

PS: the code you pasted is really verbose, what about this equivalent snippet?

```
var redirects = {
    "Mozilla": "ff",
    "Microsoft Internet Explorer": "ie",
    "Google Chrome": "ch",
    "Safari": "sa",
    "Google Chrome": "ch"
};

window.location = (redirects[navigator.appName] || "un") + "/index.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite script is this one - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html Also most of the modern libraries have browser detection built in (e.g. jQuery [browser](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.browser) object)

However it is highly recommended to use feature detection instead of browser detection. Take a look at the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library as a good example of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    if(navigator.appCodeName == "Mozilla")
    {
     window.location.href = "ff/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appCodeName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
     window.location.href = "ie/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appCodeName == "Google Chrome")
    {
     window.location.href = "ch/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appCodeName == "Safari")
    {
     window.location.href = "sa/index.html"
    }
     if(navigator.appCodeName == "Google Chrome")
    {
     window.location.href = "ch/index.html"
    }
     window.location.href = "un/index.html"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **none of the above scripts works in enough cases, including something as basic as redirection to "Firefox 37.x" (!!)** — the worst being "Google Chrome" (very stubborn) —, now: the only "old school"* approach that I found **WORKING**:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm

Below: my modified (quick/dirty/you're welcome to clean it) "version", since what we want here is a **redirection**, instead of displaying browsers code names etc.

- Note: the author KWOWS, about that overall method flaws — and warns.

I assume that anybody who reads this has understood that object detection / browsers capabilities detection is now (Sept. 2015) promoted as a far better method — EXCEPT... this:

1st of all, it's not 100% reliable either ; and, above all, one may want a simpler approach, or quicker, especially when the need is to modify an existing website (as slightly as possible), instead of having to recode almost eveything, switch to CSS and so on, for... ages!

Tested using: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

*( http://stackoverflow.com as a test redirection URL does not seem to work, on that W3schools page, neither Google's, while personal websites URLs worked)*

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera 15+, the true version is after "OPR/" 
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("OPR/"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+4);
}
// In older Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5)
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7)
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com"
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8)
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

</script></head><body>
```